# Raspberry Pi suddenly lost internet connection? (Connected to internet via Ethernet to Mac)

Tags: wifi, ethernet, internet

Good day everyone, I was working on my raspberry pi when I suddenly lost my internet connection. I followed [this guide](https://galem.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/configuring-the-raspberry-pi-to-share-a-macs-internet-connection/) last night and everything was working fine, my RaspberryPi was able to connect to the internet without problems.

However, a couple of hours ago, the Rπ can no longer connect to the internet even though I didn't touch the internet settings.

Here are the settings for the Ethernet for the Macbook Pro:

[image]

And then I just copied the DHCP from the WiFi one to the Ethernet and it worked last night.

This is the nameserver:

```
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

and the for the network interfaces:

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

I'm not really sure what suddenly cut the internet connection to my Rπ and I'd be more than happy if someone can point out how I can fix it.

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1

Comment: Unless you are using an old Pi and a 2½ year old version of Raspbian, following this link seems futile. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) If you want to use ICS on the Mac, the Pi would work out of the box, with no fiddling.

Comment: @Milliways I'm using a RaspberryPi  2 Model B V1.1 but I got the latest NOOBS OS.

Comment: And I'm connected to the Macbook Pro and not the Router.